# Regsub use for set text [join $text \n] for missing brace error

Tags: tcl

I am getting missing closing brace error for the line

`set text [join $text \n]`
my entire code is

```
proc ProcessText { text} {
   regsub -all -- ({) $text {\{} text 
   set text [join $text  \n]
   return $text
}

##it starts from here
set text "{a b c"
puts $text
puts [ProcessText $text]
```

If I am using regsub to replace the { to any proper substitution that will not throw error, I am getting error
"Missing close-brace while executing"proc ProcessText {}"

if I comment regsub then I get error
"unmatched open brace in list while executing
"join $text  \n"
Can anyone please suggest me here how to proceed for the same in tcl.

FYI:
text is a list which contains lot of textual information in which a { is also there, if i remove the {. It works other wise not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are describing... The error is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Pls. post the exact error report (stack trace) and the reduced script under execution.

Comment: The _immediate_ problem is that your variable `text` does not contain a proper list; the `join` command works only on a list as its input. (The issue is likely to be related to unbalanced braces or double quotes, but that's pure guesswork.) What are you trying to do? We need more context in order to help you choose the correct operation.

Comment: @all Can you please check now, I have given the entire code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Donal has sensed already, it is the formatting of the value hold by variable `text` that does not conform to a Tcl list, which is expected by `[join]`, however.

Your options are:

1) Turn the value into a Tcl list by using [`[split]`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm):

```
join [split $text] \n
```

2) Avoid the conversion into a list and `[join]` altogether by using [`[string map]`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
string map {" " "\n"} $text
```

(or use `[regsub]` as below, if you can't control white-space proliferation in your input)

Sometimes, a string better stays just a string ;)

### Varia

Your use of `[regsub]` is problematic, foremost, better use it once to obtain your ultimate goal, rather than sanitizing the input string before calling `[join]`:

```
 regsub -all {\s+} $text "\n"
```

### Background

You run into errors because you do not escape the sentinel `{` in the regular expression `({)` to `[regsub]` correctly:

```
regsub -all -- ({) $text {\{} text
```

This should be:

```
regsub -all -- {\{} $text {\{} text
```

In your variant, `{` is considered an opening brace that is, actually, not matched in the remainder of the script.